# Java multi-bit / compact small integer array

Tags: java, data-structures, bitset, bloom-filter, bitsets

I am working on implementing some bloom filter variants, and a very useful data structure for this would be a compact multi-bit array; that is, an array where each element is a compact integer of around 4 bits.

Space efficiency is of the utmost importance here, so while a plain integer array would give me the functionality I want, it would be bulkier than necessary.

Before I try to implement this functionality myself with bit arithmetic, I was wondering if anyone knows of a library out there that already provides such a data structure.

Edit: Static size is fine.
The ideal case would be an implementation that is flexible with regard to the number of bits per cell.  That might be a bit much to hope for though (no pun intended?).

Comment: What about [`java.util.BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, BitSet is 1 bit per cell.  I could implement what I'm looking for on top of that with some bit arithmetic (or for that matter on top of an int array with 16 4-bit cells per int), but this seems like a generic enough use case that I'm hoping someone out there has already done it.

Comment: May I suggest a byte[]? It's longer than you want at 8 bits, but it's a basic type so it should work faster than bit munging a four-bit array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you aren't modifying the array after creation, `java.util.BitSet` does all the bit masking for you but is slow to access since you have to fetch each bit individually and do the masking yourself to re-create the int from 4 bits.

Having said that writing it yourself might be the best way to go.  Doing the bit arithmetic yourself isn't that difficult since it's only 2 values per byte so decoding the high bits are `(array[i] & 0xF0) >> 4` and the low bits are `array[i] & 0x0F`

Comment: I may end up just doing this.  It becomes much more complicated though if I end up wanting, say, 6 bits instead of 4.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the compressed BitSet provided by http://code.google.com/p/javaewah/, it allows to set bits freely and will ensure that it uses memory efficiently via compression algorithms being used.

I.e. something like

```
        EWAHCompressedBitmap32 set = new EWAHCompressedBitmap32();
        set.set(0);
        set.set(1000000);
```

will still only occupy a few bytes, not one MB as with the Java BitSet...

You should be able to map the 4-bit integer to the BitSet by multiplying the index into the BitSet accordingly